# JQUERY: Getting Results using if statments from two characters

Tags: jquery

I am trying to Create a statement in jQuery like the following below but if i changed the var parttest to CBA and i submit the results are always "Worked" 
just seeing if anyone could help me out
Thanks !

var parttest = ABC

```
   if (parttest = "ABC") {
alert("worked");
}
    else{
alert("Nothing their");
}
```

Comment: `parttest == "ABC"` you need to use `==`(equality operator) not `=`(assignment operator)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `===/==` instead of `=`, because as we all know `=` will assign the value to the variables, and it will not compare them.

```
if (parttest === "ABC") {
  alert("worked");
}
else{
  alert("Nothing their");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` for comparison or `===` for comparison in strict mode, so you can do:

```
if (parttest == "ABC") {
```

or:

```
if (parttest === "ABC") {
```

Currently, you're using `=` which is used for assigment.

You can read more about **[Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)**

Answer (score 0):

You need `===`

`if (parttest === "ABC")`